# generating a specific string from contents in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file full of video game names like this:

```
AlienBlaster
TombStealer
SwordMaster
etc...
```

I want to generate a big insert statement from the names in that file like this:

```
INSERT INTO GameNames (Name, GroupId) VALUES
('AlienBlaster', 193),
('TombStealer', 193),
('SwordMaster', 193);


with open('GameNames.txt', encoding='utf-8)') as my_file:
    Aff_array = my_file.readlines()
l1 = []

print('INSERT INTO GameNames(Name, GroupId) VALUES\n')        

for elem in Aff_array:
    l1.extend(elem.strip().split('\n')) 
    print (', '.join("'{0}'".format(w) for w in l1), 193)
```

I don't get any errors, I just get a long list of the names and 193 and my output looks like this:

```
λ python createInsertFromFile.py                 
INSERT INTO GameNames(Name, GroupId) VALUES  

 'AlienBlaster' 193                                             
 'AlienBlaster','TombStealer' 193                                             
 'AlienBlaster','TombStealer','SwordMaster' 193                                             
 etc...
```

I'm not sure why it's putting the game names more than once.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO GameNames(Name, GroupId) VALUES

('AlienBlaster
', 193), ('TombStealer
', 193), ('SwordMaster
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop already loops on lines, so I'm  not sure why you try to split on '\n'.

On each iteration in your loop you extend your list l1, which is each time extended with one more element from Aff_array. Instead of that you just want to print something like that:

```
print('('{0}', {1}),'.format(elem, 193))
```

Or, as you tried to use join, you could try something like that, without any looping:

```
print(', '.join(['(\'{0}\', {1})'.format(elem, 193) for elem in Aff_array]) + ';')
```

Comment: I tried your 2nd line of code, but the output doesn't put sinqle quotes around the names of the game and it's also putting a linebreak after each comma

Comment: I slightly edited the answer,  but feel free to adapt it,  it was just a suggestion. About linebreaks, that's how you formatted the result you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks!  I just used that and it's working, but for some reason it's putting a line break after the last letter in the game...I edited my question and put what I'm seeing at the end of the question...

Comment: I should have left the stip() call... instead of format(elem, 193), you  can try format(elem.strip(), 193)